# Last page active by Default Codeigniter pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I have been searching solution for my problem but i can't find an answer to it. My problem i believe is different than what normally others will be facing with codeigniter pagination library.

What i am try to doing?
I have use codeigniter library and its work perfectly but i want to do active last page by default when i use this code it will always active first page by default.

```
public function example1() {
    $config = array();
    $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "welcome/example1";
    $config["total_rows"] = $this->Countries->record_count();
    $config["per_page"] = 20;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    $data["results"] = $this->Countries->
        fetch_countries($config["per_page"], $page);
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    $this->load->view("example1", $data);
}
```

Now my link look like

**1** 2 3 4 5

1 page is active by default but i want to active what ever last page in this case it's 5 which could be active

1 2 3 4 **5**

Comment: Possbile duplicate question [Codeigniter Pagination first page is always current page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18939040/codeigniter-pagination-first-page-is-always-current-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define current page on Codeigniter with;

```
$config["cur_page"] = $your_last_page_number;
```

and manage pages in controller.

Answer (score 0):

@Muhammad Talha if i didn't misunderstand u this is a solution for design some effect for Codeigniter default pagination

just `echo $link;` inside a div

View file

```
<div class="my-pagination">
     <?php echo $link; ?>
</div>
```

and use this simple css if u use default Codeigniter pagination

```
.my-pagination a,.my-pagination strong{padding: 5px 10px;margin:0px 0px;}
.my-pagination strong{cursor:not-allowed;background:#333;color:#fff;box-shadow:0 0 5px #333;border:none;}
.my-pagination a:first-child{border:1px solid #ddd;border-right:none;}
.my-pagination a{border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;border-top:1px solid #ddd;transition: all .2s ease-in-out;}
.my-pagination a:last-child{border:1px solid #ddd;border-left:none;}
```

Comment: thanks for your time and answer but this is not my answer i am asking about how we can show last page in codeigniter pagination by default. for example my total pages is 5 and by default codeigniter show records of first page but i want to show records of last page.

Comment: @MuhammadTalha i don't know why u want to start with Page 5 as default, maybe u want to show last record 1st but i think use `$this->db->order_by('field_name', 'desc');` in ur query so 1st page will get data as ur order by last record

Answer (score 0):

You can change your this line as :

```
$page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 4;
```

Comment: yes i try this its working fine its show last page record but if we see pagination links design then we see first page is active and we have records form last page.